# How do I zip a csv file and write that zipped file to a folder using R

Tags: r, csv, rscript

I have an R script which generates a csv file of nearly 80000 KB after calculations. I want to write this csv file to folder say `D:/My_Work/Output` with file name `result.zip` as a zipped file. Please suggest  is there any function or any way that i could achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `zip` function:

```
zip(*path to zip*,*path to csv*)
```

edit: Unfortunately you cannot go from data.frame straight to zipped csv. You need to explicitly make the csv, but it wouldn't be hard to write a wrapper that deletes the csv so that you never know its there like so:

```
zipped.csv <- function(df, zippedfile) {
  # init temp csv
  temp <- tempfile(fileext=".csv")
  # write temp csv
  write.csv(df, file=temp)
  # zip temp csv
  zip(zippedfile,temp)
  # delete temp csv
  unlink(temp)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: Instead of writing my resulting dataframe into a csv file, then reading it and zipping it, Is there any way that I can directly save a dataframe as a zipped csv file into a folder? Correct me if my perception is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just save some space on the disk then it is more convenient to use *.gz compression.

```
write.csv(iris, gzfile("iris.csv.gz"), row.names = FALSE)
iris2 = read.csv("iris.csv.gz")
```

Comment: Thanks @Gregory. I would try this.