# r:readr:write_csv how to have the file compressed?

Tags: r, zip, readr

A CSV file of 20MB+ is not polite to email. 
How a user can zip the file with least amount of code?

Non zipped task is:

```
mtcars %>% write_csv('foocars.csv')
```

read_csv can nicely look at extensions and do unzipping. What would be easiest way of doing (not correct code)

```
mtcars %>% write_csv('foocars.csv.zip')               
mtcars %>% write_csv('foocars.csv',zipIt=T)
```

No linux tar or gz please. It has to be for win users.

Comment: similar question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487628/how-do-i-zip-a-csv-file-and-write-that-zipped-file-to-a-folder-using-r

Answer (score 5):

For .gz it seems possible. It is not full answer since I need .zip

```
write_csv(mtcars,gzfile('mtcars.csv.gz'))
testingIt<-read_csv('mtcars.csv.gz')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `zip` function to create a zipped version of the csv file.

```
mtcars %>% write_csv('foocars.csv')
zip("foocars.zip", "foocars.csv")
```

This should work on all platforms, but note that an external program is used. As per the man page for `zip`:

> On a Unix-alike, the default for ‘zip’ will by default use the
>        value of ‘R_ZIPCMD’, which is set in ‘etc/Renviron’ if an ‘unzip’
>        command was found during configuration.  On Windows, the default
>        relies on a ‘zip’ program (for example that from Rtools) being in
>        the path.